# Remove specified element from associated array

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am looking for ways to delete the elements from associate array.
I need to remove values like null and '' while in the loop. But I cant because I know that  I will need to identify and the build array to store, Then use elements in the new array to seek and remove them.

```
var storeData3 = [
  { 'key' : 'value1' },
  { 'key' : 'value2' },
  { 'key' : 'value3' },
  { 'key' : null },
  { 'key' : '' },
  { 'key' : 'value10'}
];
```

Comment: Loop from the end of the array to the beginning and splice the array if the specific key's value is invalid to you

Comment: How hard are you looking? I can't imagine it's that difficult to find a solution on StackOverflow or elsewhere. ...I see a link on this very page that would seem to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

Using `Array.filter` to get the data after omitting unwanted data.

```
 var result= storeData3
  .filter(function(val){
       return (val.key != '' && val.key != null)});
```

[.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jAwa/)